# Why Android myActivity.runOnUiThread and uihandler.post hangs my UI?

Tags: android

I have a method invoked by onClickListener

```
@Override
    public Object getData() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new testThread());
        t.start();
        return false;
    }
```

it start the new Thread well, but when I am trying to do both:

```
private class testThread implements Runnable{
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                           OuterClass.this.myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ ... });
                           OuterClass.this.myActivity.uiHandler.post(new Runnable(){ ... });
```

...
nothing happens. UI hang up and no Runnable never run (I see it during careful debugging). 
Why? Everything should work or even if it fail, why the UI hangs??
Please help!

**SOLVED!!!**  The problem was in method which invokes getData (outside the scope), it never finished failing into infinite loop. Since that scheduled Runnables never started as I think. Now everything works .

Comment: what you want to achieve and OuterClass.this.myActivity  where it refers?

Comment: I want to update my UI setting text for some TextView.  OuterClass.this.myActivity refers to MainActivity which is FragmentActivity

Comment: why dont you use asynctask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have tried AsyncTask it start perfect, but the same - unable to run the Thread with runOnUiThread

Comment: Why do you want to create a new thread to pass a new `Runnable` to run on the main thread? Your architecture, with out more details, makes no sense to me. If you want to pass data/messages between threads the easier and recommended way is to use an event bus.

Comment: Solved! The problem was in method which invoke getData, it never finished failing into infinite loop. Since that scheduled Runnables never started as I think. Now everything works .

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is better. It is easier to use, you don't have to manually manage so many threads, and it keeps your code clean.

The `doInBackground()` method will do your lengthy task on an alternate thread. If you want to update your UI when the task is running, use the `publishProgress()` method, and if you want to update the UI after the work is done, use `onPostExecute()`.

As to your question on why the UI hangs, see if you are using any method that takes very long or blocks for some reason in the `runOnUiThread()` method. If any code takes time, remove it from this method.

Comment: Solved! The problem was in method which invokes getData, it never finished failing into infinite loop. Since that scheduled Runnables never started as I think. Now everything works .